# Spring won't detect the autowired field

Tags: spring

I'm declaring the `<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.domain.*" />` to scan for all the annotations in spring. i have declared my class under the same package

```
package com.blah.domain;

@Service
public class UserService extends BaseService implements InitializingBean {
  .....
}
```

The `BaseService` definition is as follow:-

```
@Service
public class BaseService {
  ........
}
```

I tried invoking the `UserService` through the web application as well as test case, but in both the cases, the exception is as follows

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`: Could not autowire field: `private com.blah.domain.service.UserService`

I'm pasting the spring definition below:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.domain.service.*" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `base-package` attribute takes a package name, not a wildcard, i.e. it should be

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.domain" />
```